# Java/Hibernate: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate

To make it simple, an Event has an address, and many Events can share the same address. So I have a ManyToOne relationship.

**Events class** (I removed irrelevant code for readability)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

   private Address address;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
   public Address getAddress() {
       return this.address;
   }
}
```

**Address class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "adresses")
public class Address {

   private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>(0);

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "address")
   public Set<Event> getEvents() {
       return this.events;
   }


}
```

When I fetch the Event with ID 6 and try to delete it:

```
Event e = session.get(Event.class, 6);
session.delete(e);
```

I get the error `not-null property references a null or transient value : logic.Event.address`

But it's neither transient since I'm retrieving it from the database, nor null since the Address DOES initialize:

```
Event e = session.get(Event.class, 6);
System.out.println(e.getAddress().getAddressId()); //Output is 3, which is correct
```

I have no idea why this happens, and most people with the same question were trying to save a transient object, which is not my case at all.

Comment: *No Set<Event> because I don't need it*!! But you need it so the mapping would be correct.

Comment: @chsdk Really??????? Is this causing a "null" error? lol

Comment: Yes, this should raise a mapping error, I think thta's why you got `not-null property references a null or transient value`.

Comment: @chsdk I still get the error :/

Comment: why did you initialized the `Set`?!

Comment: @chsdk It's JBoss Hibernate tools when you generate an entity class from a table. But does this have any relevance to the actual error?

Comment: I would vote, that get method returns null, as it does, when entity does not exist,. Passing null to delete method causes this problem.

Comment: @Beri That's not it, because I can sysout any field value from the Event object, including the Address object inside the Event

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `cascade` annotations on all my `@ManyToOne` side entities solved my problem. If anyone has an explanation, feel free to comment!